# Kotlin Simple Listview Remove Row

Tags: android, database, kotlin, listview, onlongclicklistener

I want to delete the long clicked line in my dynamic list I created. But I couldn't write adapter. I would be glad if you can help. If interested, I can edit the more necessary code blocks.It is not necessary to delete it with a long click. I am open to other suggestions.

> Customers.kt

```
  var compnameList=ArrayList<String>()
lateinit var  toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers)
    supportActionBar!!.setTitle("Müşteriler")




    getDataParse()



    listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

        val intent=Intent(applicationContext,CustomersDetails::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Name",compnameList[i])
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

       //İt'snot define


    }









}


fun getDataParse(){

    val search=findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.searchView)
    val listView=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)

    val arrayAdapter=ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,compnameList)
    listView.adapter=arrayAdapter
    registerForContextMenu(listView)
```

Comment: I think is as easy as just removing the element from the position by calling list.removeAt(index) and then using adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position). Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Sir, Please explain a little more because I tried something like this and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code edited with a basic list view adapter, if this is what you need:

```
var compnameList=ArrayList<String>()
lateinit var  toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers)

    supportActionBar!!.setTitle("Müşteriler")

    getDataParse()

    findViewById<ListView>(<your-list-view-id>).adapter = ListViewAdapter()
}

inner class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int = compnameList.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any = compnameList[position]

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)

        ViewHolder(view).bind(compnameList[position])

        return view
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) {

        val text1 = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.text1)

        fun bind(compname: String) {
            text1.text = compname.nome

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent=Intent(this, CustomersDetails::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Name", compname)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener {

            }
        }
    }
}
```